# node.js promise: then() of promise nested inside a then() chain doesn't get resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Writing a demo script to understand promises I nested multiple promises (using promises.all() to proceed after all promises are resolved) inside a then(). The then()s of the nested promises do not get resolved:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

var array = [];

// push promises onto array
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        for (var i = 5 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            array.push(returnapromise());
            console.log("pushed promise number", i, "onto array");
        }
        resolve();
    }, 300);
})

.then(function() {
    new Promise.all(array).then(function() {
        console.log("\nall done\n");
    });
});

// function that returns a promise
var returnapromise = function() {
    return new Promise(function(yolo) {

        new Promise(function() {
            setTimeout(function() { 
                console.log("async function within nested promise");
            }, 200);
        })

        .then(function() {
            setTimeout(function() { 
                console.log("async function within then one")
            }, 100);
        })

        .then(function() {
            setTimeout(function() { 
                console.log("async function within then two")
                yolo();
            }, 50);
        });

    }) // eof returned promise

}; // eof returnapromise()
```

However the desired goal can be achieved using callbacks inside the nested promise, like this:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

var array = [];

// push promises onto array
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        for (var i = 5 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            array.push(returnapromise());
            console.log("pushed promise number", i, "onto array");
        }
        resolve();
    }, 300);
})

.then(function() {
    new Promise.all(array).then(function() {
        console.log("\nall done\n");
    });
});

// function that returns a promise
var returnapromise = function() {
    return new Promise(function(yolo) {

        new Promise(function() {
            setTimeout(function() { 
                console.log("async function within nested promise");
                one()
            }, 200);

            var one = function() {
                setTimeout(function() { 
                    console.log("cb one")
                    two();
                }, 100);
            };

            var two = function() {
                setTimeout(function() { 
                    console.log("cb two")
                    yolo();
                }, 50);
            };

        }) // eof nested promise

    }) // eof returned promise

}; // eof returnapromise()
```

How can I write nested promises which's then()s actually get resolved?

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do here?

Comment: Async functions inside of a `.then()` handler that don't themselves return a promise from the `.then()` handler are completely disconnected from the promise chain entirely and do not affect it at all.  There appear to be lots of things wrong here, but I don't know what you're really trying to achieve so I'm not sure exactly what to suggest.

Comment: In addition, you don't do `new  Promise.all(array)`, you just do `return Promise.all(array)`.

Comment: Inside of `returnapromise()`, you have multiple async operations that are disconnected from one another, all running in parallel, with only one that actually calls the resolve function of the parent promise.  So many things wrong, not sure where to start without knowing the actual objective.

Comment: @jfriend00 that's why I asked :)

Comment: What I actually want to do is getting a file list from a server, afterwards download files that are on the list, edit and save them.

Comment: @r0bs - We could all help you much better if you wrote a new question that described what you were actually trying to do and showed what code you've tried so far and described what problems you ran into.  Abstract questions are so hard to be very specific about.  Specific questions can attract very good answers quickly.

Comment: Got it! Though I want to grasp the concept of promises, therefore wrote an abstract example of what I actually want to do.

Comment: For the future, please ask about the real problem, not an abstract problem.  This site works way, way, way better with real problems.

Comment: @jfriend00 Will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first version of `returnapromise()`, you create two promises, one nested inside of the other.

The inside promise is never resolved (there is no code to ever resolve it).  As such, it never calls its `.then()` handlers which means that the `yolo()` function is never called which means the outer promise is never resolved.  So, it is just stuck forever.

You can fix that by resolving the inner promise in that first `setTimeout()`, then then that still leaves the second `setTimeout()` disconnected from the whole promise chain.

You can rewrite `returnapromise()` like this:

```
function delay(t, val) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(val);
            resolve(val);
        }, t);
    });
}

// function that returns a promise
var returnapromise = function() {
    return delay(200, "async function within nested promise").then(function() {
        return delay(100, "async function within then one");
    }).then(function() {
        return delay(50, "async function within then two");
    });
}; // eof returnapromise()
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/k1q60Lep/

Comment: Thanks! When I add a resolve function to the most inner promise and then call `yolo()` to resolve the promise which gets returned by the `returnapromise()` everything is executed. Unfortunately the `promise.all()` gets resolved before the `then()`s of the most inner promise. How can I solve this?

Comment: @r0bs - If you put the `resolve()` inside the first `setTimeout()`, then the second `setTimeout()` will execute, but the third one will not wait for it because the second one is not connected to your promise chain in any way.  You just shouldn't be running async operations inside a `.then()` handler that don't return a promise from the handler because that just leaves those async operation uncoordinated with what's going on around them.  Note how in my code example, every `.then()` handler that contains another async operation returns a promise from that async operation.

Comment: @r0bs - I can't comment on code you've changed and I cannot see.  I've explained in both my answer and in my previous comment how you coordinate async operations inside of `.then()` handlers.

Comment: Just seen your edit! - Thanks a lot! That should work for me!

Comment: @JaromandaX - yes, but I'm trying to show the OP how to make their own functions that return promises and then how to use them in `.then()` handlers.

Comment: @jfriend00 - fair enough - I'm surprised one of the Promise nazis hasn't jumped all over it with `avoid Promise constructor` crap they usually go on with just because their favourite Promise library has sugar that uses a Promise constructor for you - that's what usually happens if I answered like you did :p

Comment: @JaromandaX - My answer also purposely doesn't use Bluebird to make it a generic answer about ES6 promises.